# Passing data of custom annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

How can I pass the data of `Custom` annotation? I use this function to perform segue:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {}
```

---

```
class Custom: MKPointAnnotation { 
    var name: String?
    var time: String?
    var address: String?
}
```

Comment: not enought information. Please add more details

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: use lower letter with variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    let anno = view.annotation as! Custom 
    print(anno.name)
    // then access the properties of anno and use them for the segue
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"SegueID",sender:anno)
} 

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if segue.identifier == "SegueID" {

    let des = segue.destination as! SecondVC
    des.ann = sender as! Custom 
  }
}

class SecondVC:UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var lbl:UILabel!
   var ann:Custom!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.lbl.text = ann.name
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you please write next steps? I just newbie in coding and don't understand some things. I need to pass data to Information View Controller. There it will be transformed to UILabel. How can i do this? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, it works! Only one moment to ask, how will change code if i need pass not one String but two.